# Problem access Joomla User Groups via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

As a newbie I'm struggling with calling a variable, I have a MySQL SELECT query with a WHERE clause:

```
WHERE table_name.j_group_id IN ('".$jgroup."')
```

but it does not return any results.
The table_name.j_group_id is 11 and if I print_r the $jgroup array it returns:

Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 8 [3] => 2 [4] => 11 )

so 11 is within the array, but why does it not work?

If I change the SELECT query to:

```
WHERE table_name.j_group_id IN (2, 11, 14, 18) it works as expected.
```

Just as a background, the $jgroup returns the Joomla users Authorised Groups. I have created Groups for each team, the Group ID has been manually added to the users details within the tables, when a team manger logs in, their Groups ID (picked up from with $jgroup) will match their team members (same Groups ID) and they will have access to their content. This is so I can have one editable page, accessible by all managers, but will only display the staff under that manager.

Thanks in advance and I hope it makes sense!

Comment: Based on the small PHP snippet you've provided, it is likely that your code is vulnerable to a critical [SQL injection vulnerability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection). Use [Parameterized Queries](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating PHP variables directly into your queries to mitigate this.

Comment: It looks like you are not implementing secure querying practices and Joomla has dedicated helper methods specifically for this purpose.  Please post all Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Comprehensive advice at JSE: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/22898/12352

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably caused by the format of your array.

You could try to structure the array before you add it into your query.

```
$jGroupList = implode(",",$jgroup);
$query .= "WHERE table_name.j_group_id IN (".$jGroupList.")
```

For debugging stuff like that it always helps to print out the acutal query your code creates an test that one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Chris, I've just been looking again at it and found the solution;

```
WHERE table_name.j_group_id IN (".implode(',', $jgroup).")
```

Has worked, thanks for taking the time to answer though.